# Filter array in a category/extension

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

For convenience, in a little experiment I am doing, I would like to extend Array to provide some app specific functionalities. This specific extension is not necessary best practice, but I am just curious about solving the Swift issues I am having.

Given a custom class Section, my extension (with partially extended closure) is:

```
extension Array {

    func onlyFullSection() -> Array<Section> {

        return self.filter {
            (a:Section) -> Bool in
            return a.isFullSection()
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get is: "T" is not a subtype of "Section".

I tried to fix it with all the sauces (changing types, casting, etc...) but still get similar errors.

This other variant:

```
extension Array {

    func onlyFullSection() -> Array<Section> {

        return (self as Array<Section>).filter {
            (a:Section) -> Bool in
            return a.isFullSection()
        } as Array<Section>
    }
```

throws: `Cannot convert the expression's type 'Array<Section>' to type 'Array<Section>'`

Any clue on what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are extending T[] and not Section[]. That means that Int[] will also have your additional method. That might not be the best idea (since it will crash badly).

Swift currently does not allow you to extend a specialised generic type like Section[].

But if you really, really want to do it, here is one way to force a cast, use `reinterpretCast`, which Apple describes as follows

```
/// A brutal bit-cast of something to anything of the same size
func reinterpretCast<T, U>(x: T) -> U
```

You can use it like this:

```
extension Array {
    func onlyFullSection() -> Section[] {
        let sections : Section[] = reinterpretCast(self)
        return sections.filter{ $0.isFullSection() }
    }
}
```

But please don't.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that since the `Array` class is actually a generic `Array<T>`, you are extending `Array<T>`. And apparently you can't cast between generic types (i.e. `<T>` to `<Section>`), so I believe you'll have to make a new array and just push the appropriate objects into it.

```
 17> extension Array {
 18.     func onlyFullSection() -> Array<Section> {
 19.         var ary = Array<Section>()
 20.         for s in self {
 21.             if (s as Section).isFullSection() {
 22.                 ary.append(s as Section)
 23.             }
 24.         }
 25.         return ary
 26.     }
 27. }
```

You could also create a helper method to convert between generic types for you, but in this instance that would just create an unnecessary temporary object.

Remember that the language is still heavily in flux so it's possible this will change. I think it's unlikely that we'll get the ability to cast between generic types, but I hope we'll at least be able to extend particular generics.